# Get app path without trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my code I use the tilde to get the app path like so:

```
 <a href="~/">home</a>
```

However this results in my link looking like:

```
<a href="/appname/">home</a>
```

Is there any way to use the tilde so that it will produce a link without the trailing slash as it is causing unnecessary redirects which is penalising us on seo:

```
<a href="/appname">home</a>
```

I tried just `"~"` but obviously that doesn't work - the best I have come up with is `@Url.Content("~/").TrimEnd('/');` but seems a bit daft - surely there is a better way?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? Also, are you using the razor syntax of `@Html.ActionLink` or just a usual `<a>` tag? I typed the following into my MVC5 project `<li><a href="~/">TEST</a></li>` and it was rendered as exactly that

Comment: You could try with `routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false` in the `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` of your `RouteConfig` class, if this is MVC5 or MVC6

Comment: @mituw16 Just an anchor rather than actionlink.  MVC 5.2.3

Comment: @r1verside just tried but the link still adds the trailing slash - any particular place it needs to go in the route config?

Comment: @Pete That is very odd behavior. Do have your app hosted in a sub folder? I am unable to duplicate that behavior in our MVC5 app. I even changed my test link to `~/TEST` and it was rendered in chrome as `/TEST`

Comment: @mituw16 if I do `~/test` that works fine - it's just the app homepage link - `~/` where you need the trailing slash for the tilde to work.  The app sits in it's own folder